# Why does blocking sites through hosts file break HTTPS?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, security, https, hosts-file

I've recently decided to give [this `hosts` file](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/zero/) a try.

Just after adding these entries on my machine I've noticed that HTTPS connection is insecure on [banking](https://www.mbank.pl/) [sites](https://www.pekao24.pl/) and [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/). Chrome shows a red padlock and warns about insecure scripts. I've tried to find mixed content scripts using Inspector, but I haven't found any - all scripts are either loaded over HTTPS or added by Chrome extensions.

[image: Chrome HTTPS warning screenshot]

Removing new entries from the `hosts` file fixes this. What's interesting is that only some machine+browser pairs are affected:

- My main Windows 10 machine, Chrome 47: **✘ insecure**
- Same machine, Chrome updated to 48: **✘ insecure**
- Same machine, another instance of Chrome 47, no extensions: **✘ insecure**
- Same machine, Firefox 43: **✔ secure**
- Android 5.1 smartphone, Chrome 47: **✔ secure**
- Another Windows 10 machine, Chrome 47: **✘ insecure**

**What's wrong with Chrome on Windows? How do I diagnose which entry causes this issue? Is there any better method than bisecting that `hosts` file?**

Here's mbank.pl certificate information from Chrome 47:

[image: Certificate information screenshot]
[image: Certificate information screenshot]

It seems that all four affected sites that I'm aware of:

- https://www.mbank.pl/
- https://www.pekao24.pl/
- https://www.paypal.com/
- https://www.live.com/

have one thing in common: they use Symantec certificate. [SSL Labs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=live.com&s=157.56.19.81) confirms that it's correct.

Comment: What's the certificate information say? What you've blocked may be relevant too

Comment: Because hosts wasn't meant to block content.  You have Symantec software installed that's what has broken https not your hosts file changes.  Firefox only works because it uses its own certificate store which Symantec hasn't infected

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, check the first link in my question for the `hosts` entries. I've added cert details.

Comment: @Ramhound, there is no Symantec software on these machines and there never was. I have installed OSes myself, so I'm also sure I don't have any manufacturer crapware. It's a good point, though, that all affected sites I'm aware of use Symantec certificate.

Comment: Might be related to https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.sg/2015/10/sustaining-digital-certificate-security.html and http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/10/still-fuming-over-https-mishap-google-gives-symantec-an-offer-it-cant-refuse/ the second link would be core of an answer if it was june... did google start blacklisting symantec early?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, that doesn't explain why reverting changes to the `hosts` file makes these certificates valid again.

Comment: Well it's saying your loading an insecure script, have you identified, what that script is?

Comment: @Ramhound, "insecure" is pretty vague term. I've tried to look for mixed content scripts manually and with jjlin's method, but I haven't found anything suspicious.

Comment: I tried the hosts file you referenced in Chrome 48, and I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. All the sites you listed show no errors, and I can see things in the host file being blocked. What do you see in the `Network` tab in developer tools when an element gets blocked?

Comment: Insecure means http if it was a script over https it wouldn't complain and it's not that vague ....

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 48 actually has a new feature for debugging mixed content issues.

1. Open the connection security panel and click `Details`:

   [image: Connection security panel]
2. This opens a Security Overview panel; click `View requests in Network Panel`:

   [image: Security overview panel]
3. Reload the page to show the mixed content elements:

   [image: Mixed content elements]

Comment: I've tried this on two affected sites and the list was empty. (Yes, I have refreshed)